# Hold to record and click to send message button

Tags: android

I'm trying to have the same functionality as WhatsApp.
If there is no text in the EditText the record button is shown, where I can click and hold (after some 200ms I guess) and start recording some audio. 
When I stop holding the audio is sent.
If there is text, the send button is shown and the audio record functionality obviously doesn't apply.

What I've tried:

```
audio_message_button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) && buttonState == StateButton.FINAL_STATE) {
                    //clique simples
                    //sendMessage(v);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clique simples", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                } else if (buttonState == StateButton.INITIAL_STATE) {
                    //long press
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        //conversationPresenter.startRecordingAudio();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Segurando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        //conversationPresenter.stopRecording();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Soltei", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The state is a variable that I get from my custom view (which changes after some TextWatcher)

But it is not working,the "Clique Simples" Toast is never shown.
Any help is appreciated !

Comment: debug. does `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)` ever return true? Do you ever set buttonState to `FINAL_STATE` . It seems like the if statement is never `True` so never runs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even if I take out the FINAL_STATE part it never returns true.